# Help with Lagrange multipliers on an intresting function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Hi guys I am trying to do Lagrange multipliers to figure out $\lambda$ 
$$F=a \log(x^2-y)+b\log(x^3-z)-\lambda (x^2-y+x^3-z -1)$$
Where a and b are constants and we have the constraint $x^2-y+x^3-z =1$

What I did was take the partials and added them together and got $a(\frac{2x-1}{x^2-y})+b(\frac{3x-1}{x^3-z})- \lambda (2x+3x^2)+2 \lambda$

I am not sure how to find this lambda

Comment: You took "the partials"? What partials? And didn't you equalled all the four partial derivatives to zero? And why do you wrote parentheses after $\;a,b\;$ ? Did you mean the function is $\;a\log(x^2-y)+b\log(x^3-z)-$ etc., or something else?

Comment: I put the extra bracets just because I am use to while typing no xpecial meaning. Second yes the partials with respect to x ,y,z and I did set them each equal to zero. Then I knew a standard trick that worked in the ast was to add the equations of all partial derivatives. That is how I got the last Equation

Comment: Extra parentheses sometimes can be confusing, and you even forgot a right one in the second term. Anyway, isn't there more info about this? The equations resulting from the first partials are pretty nasty and it doesn't look as if something smooth can be done here. Perhaps some trick...

Comment: Yeah I know they are not nice, I tried couple of things to no avail. But this is the problem as it stands

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your $\log$ means natural logarithm. Then set the partial derivatives to $0$:
$$\frac{2ax}{x^2-y}+\frac{3bx^2}{x^3-z}-2x\lambda+3x^2\lambda=0 \\
\frac{-a}{x^2-y}+\lambda=0  \\
\frac{-b}{x^3-z}+\lambda=0\\
x^2-y+x^3-z =1$$
From equation 2 and 3:
$$\lambda=\frac{a}{x^2-y}=\frac{b}{x^3-z}$$
Plug these information into 1:
$$2x\lambda+3x^2\lambda-2x\lambda+3x^2\lambda=0$$

Can you go on from here?